# android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" doesn't work on API +17

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, android-sensors, portrait

I want my application to work in Portrait & reversePortrait mode .. In other words, I want it to work in portrait and make it rotatable 180 degrees!

I'm using the following code within `<activity>` tag of the **MainActivity** in the Manifest.

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

However, this seems to work only on ***Android 4.1.2*** and backward.

It doesn't work on ***Android 4.2.2*** and above!

I tried on different phones, the same result! How to solve it?

Comment: On your device: System settings/Display/Rotation. Enable the 180° option (disabled by default).

Comment: @BobMalooga I'm debugging with Android 4.2.2 | I didn't find anything like that in Dispaly Settings, only the main rotation-enable checkbox

Comment: On my Nexus 6 it doesn't work also, but autorotate enabled

Comment: On my MOTO 4, I couldn't get `sensorPortrait` to work properly. It would never support upside down Portrait (i.e. `reversePortrait`). However, using `fullSensor` did work but it had the caveat of also allowing landscape. That ended up being fine for me but if you only want `portrait` and `reversePortrait`, you can intercept the orientation change in your Activity with `onConfigurationChanged` and `newConfig.orientation` and just ignore or override landscape changes.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter how did you exactly do this?

Comment: @swalkner Google `onConfigurationChanged` and you'll see some examples. As I stated in my comment, we never had to do this because we allow portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of a typo error by Google that replaced `sensorPortrait` by `sensorPortait` at some point.

Not sure if that is your case, but depending on your `targetApi`, it might.

Use **sensorPortait** and see what happens at compilation.

*This has been fixed in API 16.*

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. Lint might not allow you to compile though, so it may be necessary to fiddle with Lint settings on that one.

Comment: Or set your targetApi at API >= 16. Even lint should then be okay, I think.

Comment: Targeting an old API level is generally not a good idea, though.

Comment: How do you guys supress this error? I have add <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection --> it is not look like red in android studio, but it give me error on compilation stage http://screencloud.net/v/m0Ua