# Allow only 2 screen orientations in Android?

Tags: android, xml, manifest

To lock the app to run in only 1 screen orientation, we could do this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name="..."
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

The issue is, I just found out that I need to make the app also rotatable to `reversePortrait`, first thing I tried is:

```
<activity
        android:name="..."
        android:screenOrientation="portrait|reversePortrait"/>
```

But it seems that `android:screenOrientation` only allows 1 value. How else then could we achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
<activity
        android:name="..."
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
```

see  [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Comment: Also take care of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153734/androidscreenorientation-sensorportrait-doesnt-work-on-api-17